# Decrease Selenium Webdriver loading time

Tags: python, selenium

My driver is so slow so I am wondering how to make it faster.
For two lines of code. I don't know if there is a way to make it faster but I need it to be faster due to the fact it literally takes any site 10+ seconds to load

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: headless will load quicker... or use HTMLUnit.  (there are limitations to this since there is no GUI.  This may or may not work for what you are doing...)

Comment: do you create `driver` only once? There is no need to create it again for other pages. Do you run it only with `Google`? For some pages you could use `requests` + `beautifulsoup` if they don't use `JavaScript` and doesn't have complex system to detect scripts/bots.